# How to styling toMany AssociationField in edit form EasyAdmin 4

Tags: many-to-many, crud, easyadmin

I've a field books ManyToMany relation in EasyAdmin CRUD Controller:

```
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {
    yield AssociationField::new('books')
            ->setFormTypeOption('by_reference', false);
}
```

How can I change the styles of this edit form element?
Please provide an example or link to an example of how to do this.
I have read the documentation https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/fields.html#design-options.
Thanks

I tried to change the look of an element with https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/design.html#form-field-templates but failed to create a complete structure